# Link to open waze app from phonegap on ios

Tags: ios, cordova, waze

I am trying to open "Waze" App when a user clicks on the below link from a Phonegap Application.

It works well on android but doesn't work at all on IOS.

```
<a href="waze://?ll=latitude,longitude">Waze</a>
```

Do I need to do it differently for IOS?

Answer (score 5):

As indicated by the [Waze developer documentation](https://www.waze.com/about/dev) this is the correct URL scheme for iOS.

However, as also indicated on that page, on iOS9+ you need to whitelist the scheme in your application .plist:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>waze</string>
</array>
```

To do so in a Cordova app, you can either edit the plist manually in `platforms/ios/MyProject/MyProject-Info.plist` or use [cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config) plugin to add it via a block in your `config.xml`:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <config-file platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="LSApplicationQueriesSchemes">
        <array>
            <string>waze</string>
        </array>
    </config-file>
</platform>
```

Comment: Any way to send same intent content (with lat-long) in Android?

Comment: @FARID Should be possible to send the same URL syntax via an Intent: `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("waze://?ll=37.44469,-122.15971"));startActivity(intent);`

Comment: Yes, perfect that works. btw, any links for documentation, I mean updated one other than https://www.waze.com/about/dev ?

Comment: worked for me , without using the cordova-custom-config plugin, Cordova supports the config-file syntax. so no need for plugin.